# No Web data in the table `events_intraday_YYYYMMDD` in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-firebase

After I have integrated the Google Analytics with the BigQuery in Firebase console, only the analytics data from **IOS** and **ANDROID** platform are found in the table `events_intraday_YYYYMMDD`. The **WEB** data is missing in this table.

However, the **WEB** data can be found in the tables `events_YYYYMMDD`.

May I know how to make the **WEB** data appear in the table `events_intraday_YYYYMMDD`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the reply from Firebase Support team. Here is the message:

> Currently, web streams are not eligible for intraday tables in BigQuery export, and only have daily tables. Only mobile app (Android/iOS) streams will get both intraday and daily BigQuery export. We already have a request to consider adding this feature in the future. As of now, we are yet to find out any details or timelines on when (or if) this will be implemented. You can check our release notes from time to time for any updates on this.

Thanks a lot to the team for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation from here [1], app events are stored in the table named “events_intraday_YYYYMMDD" and web are stored in “events_YYYYMMDD”.

You can reach out to Firebase directly as they provide free support here [2].

[1] https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en

[2] https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: Hi @Rajeevan, thanks for your reply. 

I can see both App and Web data in the tables "events_YYYYMMDD". But, these tables are imported daily. Therefore, the data in these tables is not collected in real-time.

The table "events_intraday_YYYYMMDD" stores the real-time data (it is claimed by the your document [1]). However, I never find the Web data in this table. That is the problem.

Thanks for the support link. I will ask the support there.